# creating a recipe schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Working through making a fullstack recipe site, unsure of how to make a schema for recipes though. There might be multiple ingredients (sometimes of the same type but different times) Any help appreciated, can find a sample recipe here
https://beerandbrewing.com/dead-president-double-ipa-recipe/

and my current schema is

```
const recipeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  type: String,
  description: String,
  batchSize: Number,
  targetOG: Number,
  targetFG: Number,
  IBUs: Number,
  targetABV: Number,
  directions: String,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to define a complete schema without knowing how detailed recipe building you are going to do.

For adding multiple ingredients as hops and malts I would make a simple array structure like so:

```
const recipeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  type: String,
  description: String,
  batchSize: Number,
  mashingWater: Number,
  strikeWater: Number,
  preBoilWater: Number,
  postBoilWater: Number,
  targetOG: Number,
  targetFG: Number,
  IBUs: Number,
  targetABV: Number,
  malts: [{
      name: String,
      grams: String,
  }],
  hops: [{
    name: String,
    grams: String,
    minutes: String,
    alphaAcids: String,
    additionalInfo: String,
  }],
  mashingDirections: String,  
  boilingDirections: String,
  fermentingInstructions: String,
  yeast: String,

});
```

But as a brewer myself, I suggest you prepare to save as many simple values as you stumble upon. Some things I noticed were missing from either your schema or the example recipe.

- Mashing water
- Strike water
- Pre-boil water
- Post-boil water
- Yeast

Especially knowing the amount of water lost during the process helps you in getting constant results with ABV and IBU.

For the descriptions, the process is usually divided into boiling, mashing, and fermenting. So it might be useful to separate those to give you more choices in UI stuff

Final note on saving amounts. If you want to give options for user to save different units (lbs vs grams for example) you need to save those separately and save the amount separately from the unit (unlike I did).

It's a rough sketch but hopefully it helps towards your final structure.

edit:
Adding multiple hops and malts can be done with either pushing entries to array.

```
RecipeModel.update(
    { _id: recipe._id }, 
    { $push: { malts: maltObject } },
    done
);
```

Or by replacing the entire array

```
RecipeModel.update(
        { _id: recipe._id }, 
        { malts: [maltsObject1, matsObject2] } },
        done
);
```

Comment: Ahh thank you very helpful, one last thing I can think of, how do I then save multiple malts and hops?

Comment: I edited the original answer to include adding malts